# Call to an overrided trait method

Tags: php, traits

I would like to use traits to instanciate my objects with my DIC:

```
trait TUseContainer {

    protected $c;

    public function __construct(Container $c) {
        $this->c=$c;
    }

}

class MyClass {
    use TUseContainer;

    //Optional
    public function __construct(ClassInheritedFromContainer $c){
        TUseContainer::__construct($c);
        //MyClass __construct stuff
    }

}
```

So my questions are:

1. Does TUseContainer::__construct($c); will work?
2. If not, does parent::__construct($c); will do the trick? (I think it will not)
3. Is trait::myOverridedMethod(); a good way to call non static overrided method?
4. Do you think I should use the "as" keyword? (I think it's a bad idea)
5. Is "TUseContainer" a good name for what I intend to do?

All coments are welcome, thanks.

I'll do some tests and post results.

Comment: Check this topic http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478124/how-to-overload-class-constructor-within-traits-in-php-5-4

Comment: I have: Fatal error: Non-static method TUseContainer::__construct() cannot be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in /path/to/MyClass.php on line 12

Comment: Thanks Robert, but it's not exactly the same because the __construct is inherited and overrided. The precedence change the rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got some trivial workaround:

```
trait TUseContainer {

    protected $c;

    public function __construct(Container $c) {
        $this->setContainer($c);
    }

    protected function setContainer(Container $c){
        $this->c=$c;
    }
}

class MyClass {
    use TUseContainer;

    //Optional
    public function __construct(ClassInheritedFromContainer $c){
        $this->setContainer($c);
        //MyClass __construct stuff
    }

}
```

1. No
2. No
3. No
4. No
5. Open

All coments are still welcome