# PHP Class Has Colliding Constructor Definitions Coming From Traits

Tags: php, function, class, traits, name-collision

I have 3 files which relate one to another :

```
class/General.class.php
class/Database.class.php
class/User.class.php
```

class/General.class.php contains :

```
trait generalFunctions {

    private $unique_number;
    private $mysql_datetime;
    private $mysql_date;

    function __construct($unique_number, $mysql_datetime, $mysql_date) {
        $this->unique_number = $unique_number;
        $this->mysql_datetime = $mysql_datetime;
        $this->mysql_date = $mysql_date;
    }


    public function encryptData ($data) {
        $unique_number = $this->unique_number;
        $data = $unique_number . $data;
        return $data;
    }

}

class General {
    use generalFunctions;
}

?>
```

and class/User.class.php basically inherits from Database class :

```
class User extends Database {
    use generalFunctions;

    public function trialEncrypt ($data) {
    // some code here which need encryptData function from General class
    }
}
```

When I tried to use these classes :

```
<?php
include('config.php');
include('class/General.class.php');
include('class/Database.class.php');
include('class/User.class.php');

?>
```

I got this following error :

```
Fatal error: User has colliding constructor definitions coming from traits in /home/***/public_html/class/User.class.php on line 178
```

but when I removed `use generalFunctions;` from User class, then everything works fine.

Unfortunately, I can't use functions inside `General` class on `User` class.

How to solve this problem? I want to have functions inside the `General` class that can be used by other classes, specially class which extended from other class, such as the `User` class (extended from the `Database` class)

Comment: What is the definition of Database? Does it have a constructor? If so, that's where the collision is coming from.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to overload class constructor within traits in PHP >= 5.4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478124/how-to-overload-class-constructor-within-traits-in-php-5-4)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although, it's not posted here, I'm guessing that class/Database.class.php has a constructor in it as well. Since PHP doesn't really do function overloading, there can only be one constructor - you have two, the inherited one from Database and the other from generalFunctions.

What you'll need to do is alias your trait constructor function with the use statement

```
class User extends Database {
    use generalFunctions { 
         generalFunctions::__construct as private traitConstructor; 
    }

    public function trialEncrypt ($data) {
    // some code here which need encryptData function from General class
    }
}
```

Another Example: [How to overload class constructor within traits in PHP >= 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478124/how-to-overload-class-constructor-within-traits-in-php-5-4)

Also for reference: [PHP Traits](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: You should also create a `__construct` function that calls `$this->traitConstructor()` and possibly `parent::construct()`.

Answer (score 0):

A simple code to demonstrate that the **problem has been fixed in recent PHP versions**:

```
<?php
/* The fatal error has been fixed in PHP 5.5.21 */

trait MyTrait {
    public function __construct() {}
}

class MyParent{
    public function __construct() {}
}

class MyClass1 extends MyParent{
    use MyTrait;
}

class MyClass2 extends MyParent {
    use MyTrait;
}

$o1 = new MyClass1;
$o2 = new MyClass2;
```

Can be viewed here: https://3v4l.org/gcp9J