# Why Target class Filesystem does not exist when I try to use traite?

Tags: php, laravel, traits

In laravel 9.6 app inside my class I define $filesystem var and use it in some methods:

```
class MakeCustomControllerCommand
{
    use Stubs;

    /**
     * Filesystem instance
     *
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    protected Filesystem $filesystem;

    /**
     * Working with file
     *
     * @param Filesystem $filesystem
     */
    public function __construct(Filesystem $filesystem)
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->filesystem = $filesystem;
    }

    /**
     * Build the directory for the class if necessary.
     *
     * @param string $path
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function createDestinationDirectory($path)
    {
        if ( ! $this->filesystem->isDirectory($path)) {
            $this->filesystem->createDestinationDirectory($path, 0777, true, true);
        }

        return $path;
    }
```

At some moment I have got a lot of methods in this class and in similar classes and I created a trait app/Traits/Stubs.php file, in which with
methods I define Filesystem $filesystem var :

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use App\Enums\StubFileType;
//use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;
use Illuminate\Support\Pluralizer;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Stubs Trait
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This trait will be used for generation of files based on stubs.
|
*/

trait Stubs
{

    /**
     * Filesystem instance
     *
     * @var Filesystem
     */
    protected \Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem $filesystem;


        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            echo '<pre>-1</pre>';
            // I try to init Filesystem class
            $this->filesystem = app(\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::class);
            echo '<pre>-2</pre>'; // I SEE THIS OUTPUT
        }



    /**
     * Return the source stub source controller file path
     *
     * @return string
     *
     */
    public function getStubSourceFilePath( StubFileType $stubFilePath): string
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($stubFilePath->value, ' -1 $stubFilePath->value::'));
        echo '<pre>-3</pre>'; // I DO NOT SEE THIS OUTPUT !
        if ( ! $this->filesystem->exists($stubFilePath->value)) {
            echo '<pre>-4</pre>';
            $this->error("Source stub controller file : {$stubFilePath->value} not found");
        }
        echo '<pre>-5</pre>';

        return $stubFilePath->value;
    }

}
```

But I got error :

```
$ php  artisan make:custom-controller ProductCategory showDone  transactionWithInterface
<pre>-1</pre><pre>-2</pre>
   Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException

  Target class [App\Console\Commands\Filesystem] does not exist.

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:891
    887▕
    888▕         try {
    889▕             $reflector = new ReflectionClass($concrete);
    890▕         } catch (ReflectionException $e) {
  ➜ 891▕             throw new BindingResolutionException("Target class [$concrete] does not exist.", 0, $e);
    892▕         }
    893▕
    894▕         // If the type is not instantiable, the developer is attempting to resolve
    895▕         // an abstract type such as an Interface or Abstract Class and there is

      +19 vendor frames
  20  artisan:35
      Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel::handle()
```

and using of this stab in app/Console/Commands/MakeCustomControllerCommand.php :

```
public function handle()
{
    $destinationPath = $this->getDestinationControllerFilePath();
    \Log::info(varDump($destinationPath, ' -1 handle $destinationPath::'));
    if ( ! $destinationPath) {
        return;
    }

    $this->createDestinationDirectory(dirname($destinationPath));

    $contents = $this->getSourceStubFileContent();

    if ( ! $this->filesystem->exists($destinationPath) or $this->overwriteFile) {
        $this->filesystem->put($destinationPath, $contents);
        $this->info("File : {$destinationPath} created");
    } else {
        $this->error("File : {$destinationPath} already exits");
    }

}
```

Full log of the error is :

```
[2024-02-01 16:57:45] local.ERROR: Target class [App\Console\Commands\Filesystem] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Console\\Commands\\Filesystem] does not exist. at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:891)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1043): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(959): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass()
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(920): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies()
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(280): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(301): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->resolve()
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(161): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\{closure}()
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(82): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->bootstrap()
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(417): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->__construct()
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(155): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->getArtisan()
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#18 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"App\\Console\\Commands\\Filesystem\" does not exist at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:889)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(889): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1043): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(959): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass()
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(920): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies()
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(280): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(301): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->resolve()
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(161): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\{closure}()
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(82): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->bootstrap()
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(417): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->__construct()
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(155): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->getArtisan()
#18 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#19 {main}
"}
[2024-02-01 16:59:51] local.ERROR: Target class [App\Console\Commands\Filesystem] does not exist. {"exception":"[object] (Illuminate\\Contracts\\Container\\BindingResolutionException(code: 0): Target class [App\\Console\\Commands\\Filesystem] does not exist. at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:891)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1043): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(959): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass()
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(920): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies()
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(280): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(301): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->resolve()
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(161): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\{closure}()
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(82): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->bootstrap()
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(417): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->__construct()
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(155): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->getArtisan()
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#18 {main}

[previous exception] [object] (ReflectionException(code: -1): Class \"App\\Console\\Commands\\Filesystem\" does not exist at /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:889)
[stacktrace]
#0 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(889): ReflectionClass->__construct()
#1 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#2 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#3 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#4 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#5 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(1043): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#6 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(959): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveClass()
#7 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(920): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolveDependencies()
#8 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(770): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->build()
#9 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(856): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->resolve()
#10 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(706): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->resolve()
#11 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(841): Illuminate\\Container\\Container->make()
#12 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(280): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Application->make()
#13 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(301): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->resolve()
#14 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(161): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\{closure}()
#15 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Console/Application.php(82): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->bootstrap()
#16 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(417): Illuminate\\Console\\Application->__construct()
#17 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(155): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->getArtisan()
#18 /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/BiCurrencies/artisan(35): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Console\\Kernel->handle()
#19 {main}
"}
```

I do not see why error and how it can be fixed ?
I want to keep $this->filesystem var inside of trait and use it in methods of the trait...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when the constructor of `class MakeCustomControllerCommand` runs it looks for the Filesystem class in the same namespace as the class is considering you  did not 'specify' anything more.

The trait could initialize the filesystem because you did:

`use Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem;`

and also:

`app(\Illuminate\Filesystem\Filesystem::class);`

However you may just delete the trait constructor and move it in the `class MakeCustomControllerCommand`.

Also here are a couple of discussions as why constructors in traits are not good:

[How to overload class constructor within traits in PHP >= 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12478124/how-to-overload-class-constructor-within-traits-in-php-5-4)

[Laravel pass arguments in trait constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885690/laravel-pass-arguments-in-trait-constructor)